# What is listener and subcriber in pnpjs/logging?

Tags: spfx, typescript, pnpjs, logging

I'm a newbie to SPFx, I have a task to create a custom logger that can record any exception and error that happen in a web part (like serilog on .NET). I'm following a guide but there is something that confuses me

```
private customLogging(): void {
        try {
            let listener = new FunctionListener((entry: ILogEntry) => {
                try {
                    switch (entry.level) {
                        case LogLevel.Verbose:
                            //console.info(entry.message);
                            break;
                        case LogLevel.Info:
                            //console.log(entry.message);
                            break;
                        case LogLevel.Warning:
                            //console.warn(entry.message);
                            break;
                        case LogLevel.Error:
                            let advanceLogging = new CustomLogger("Sample Logging", this.context.pageContext.site.absoluteUrl, "Error Log", this.context.pageContext.user.loginName);
                            Logger.subscribe(advanceLogging);
                            break;
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(`Error executing customLogging FunctionListener - ${err}`);
                }
            });
            Logger.subscribe(listener);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(`Error initializing customLogging - ${err}`);
        }
        return;
    }
```

I'm having an issue with understanding the use of listeners and subscribe here, both their use and meaning. The guide is only able to log the error level, but I want to record everything including info and warning level, what should I do?
Also, currently, I'm using pnpjs to post the error to a SharePoint list but I feel it is not clear enough if someone wants to check the log. In the future, if I could record even Info and Warning level, it would be hard if someone only wants to see a specific LogLevel or want to see the log record of a specific date.